# .wav file doesn't work in .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jar, wav

i have 2 problems:

1) this is the code of easy sound applet:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Audio {
    static URL a = Audio.class.getResource("/arch.wav");
    static File soundFile = new File(a.getFile());
    static AudioClip theSound = null;
    static void Audio(){
        try { 
            theSound = Applet.newAudioClip(soundFile.toURL()); 
            } catch(MalformedURLException e) { 
                System.out.println(e);  
            }  // Play the audio clip...    
    }   
static void start(){
    theSound.play(); 
    }
static void stop(){
    theSound.stop();
    }
}
```

I would like to export this code in a .jar file, and then convert it to a .exe file, but once created the .jar file does not load the audio file.
I created a window with a JFrame to start and stop the audio files (with two JButton and one background image, it is loaded correctly) , and that is properly displayed, the only problem and therefore the .wav file.

2) I have the same problem above, but instead of the audio file, should I upload a photo window (JFrame), a folder containing several photos. But as for point 1) they are not loaded.
I used the following code to load them:

```
static String path = "photos/";
....
File directory = new File(path);
....
```

I think that is not a code problem, partly because through the console eclipse working properly.
Resourse folder are soddivise in three: source, photos, songs
I do not know why the .jar file does not load photos in the folder or audio file, I hope some of you can help me. thank you

Comment: Filenames "inside" a .jar file are case sensitive. Maybe your file is actually names `ARCH.WAV` or something different from `arch.wav`?

Comment: no, the name of .wav file is the same. 
I also tried to put the .wav files in the same resource directory where the images are located that can visualizzarmi correctly in the .jar file, but the audio does not play.